# Getting count of records by Group by at 2 levels

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data as below:

```
custid  date    gender  cust_type
25309   29/10/2018  M   A
25310   09/11/2018  F   B
25311   10/11/2018  O   C
25312   18/09/2018  F   D
25313   18/09/2018  O   A
25314   18/09/2018  M   B
25315   18/09/2018  F   C
25316   18/09/2018  F   D
25317   19/09/2018  M   D
25318   19/09/2018  O   B
```

My final output should be as below:

quarter total A M   F   O   TOTAL B M   F   O   TOTAL C M   F   O   TOTAL D M   F   O
2   1       1   3   1   1   1   2   0   1   1   3   1   2   0

[image]

I need the count of distinct customer for each cust_type.
Within each cust_type, i need the count of M,F,O (gender)

The output should be calculated for each quarter based on date column. I tried few suggestions in site, but its giving me wrong count, while using sum within case statement.

at present i m running seperate queries for each quarter to get cust_type count and gender count as below:

SELECT INDIVIDUAL_TYPE,COUNT(DISTINCT CUST_ID)
FROM TOT_POP_DET
WHERE DATE < (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2020','DD-MON-YYYY'))
GROUP BY CUST_TYPE

SELECT GENDER,COUNT(DISTINCT CUST_ID)
FROM TOT_POP_DET
WHERE DATE < (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2020','DD-MON-YYYY'))
AND CUST_TYPE='OTHER'
GROUP BY GENDER

Seeking help here.

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Explain the logic that you want to implement.  (3) Text tables are much preferred over images.

Comment: Please supply the SQL you tried so we can help better.

Comment: I tried the below query  SELECT 
COUNT (CASE WHEN CUST_TYPE='OTHER' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OTHER_COUNT,
SUM (CASE WHEN CUST_TYPE='OTHER'  AND GENDER='F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS F_OTHER_COUNT,
SUM (CASE WHEN CUST_TYPE='OTHER' AND GENDER='M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS M_OTHER_COUNT,
SUM (CASE WHEN CUST_TYPE='OTHER' AND GENDER='*' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OTH_OTHER_COUNT
FROM TOT_POP
WHERE DATE < (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2019','DD-MON-YYYY'))

Comment: Please provide ddl (CREATE TABLE ...) and dml (INSERT INTO..) for a basic example so we can reproduce. Please take some time to format your code as well.

Comment: please put it into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a group by DATEPART(QUARTER, [Date Column]) then do SUM(CASE ...) for the individual rows you need to count.

Below is example using your example data.

```
    Select 
         DATEPART(QUARTER, date) [Quarter],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [Total A],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'A' AND gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [A - Male],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'A' AND gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [A - Female],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'A' AND gender = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [A - Other],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [Total B],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'B' AND gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [B - Male],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'B' AND gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [B - Female],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'B' AND gender = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [B - Other],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [Total C],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'C' AND gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [C - Male],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'C' AND gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [C - Female],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'C' AND gender = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [C - Other],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [Total D],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'D' AND gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [D - Male],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'D' AND gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [D - Female],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'D' AND gender = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [D - Other] 
FROM 
         TOT_POP_DET  
WHERE 
         SNAPSHOT_DATE < (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2020','DD-MON-YYYY'))  
GROUP BY 
         DATEPART(QUARTER, date)
```

**Oracle Below**

```
Select 
         TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(date, 'QUARTER')) [Quarter],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [Total A],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'A' AND gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [A - Male],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'A' AND gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [A - Female],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'A' AND gender = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [A - Other],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [Total B],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'B' AND gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [B - Male],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'B' AND gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [B - Female],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'B' AND gender = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [B - Other],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [Total C],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'C' AND gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [C - Male],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'C' AND gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [C - Female],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'C' AND gender = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [C - Other],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [Total D],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'D' AND gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [D - Male],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'D' AND gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [D - Female],
         SUM(CASE WHEN cust_type = 'D' AND gender = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0) [D - Other] 
FROM 
         TOT_POP_DET  
WHERE 
         SNAPSHOT_DATE < (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2020','DD-MON-YYYY'))  
GROUP BY 
         TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(date, 'QUARTER'))
```

Comment: I am getting syntax error for this when i run in Oracle

Comment: Ah, I wrote that for SQL server. I threw the code into a converter and I added that below the SQL server code in my original answer.

Comment: I modified it to the syntax require and its working fine. Thanks for the answer...

Comment: Glad to hear it! Be sure to mark that this answer worked.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the logic for the `QUARTER` column so I just assumed you meant quarter of the calendar year (Jan-Mar = Q1, Apr-Jun = Q2, etc.). If you group the information by quarter and customer type, you can then pivot that information to get it in the format that you want.

#### Setup

```
create table cust_table as
select 25309 as custid ,  to_date('29/10/2018','dd/mm/yyyy') as date_val,  'M' as gender,  'A' as cust_type from dual union all
select 25310 as custid ,  to_date('09/11/2018','dd/mm/yyyy') as date_val,  'F' as gender,  'B' as cust_type from dual union all
select 25311 as custid ,  to_date('10/11/2018','dd/mm/yyyy') as date_val,  'O' as gender,  'C' as cust_type from dual union all
select 25312 as custid ,  to_date('18/09/2018','dd/mm/yyyy') as date_val,  'F' as gender,  'D' as cust_type from dual union all
select 25313 as custid ,  to_date('18/09/2018','dd/mm/yyyy') as date_val,  'O' as gender,  'A' as cust_type from dual union all
select 25314 as custid ,  to_date('18/09/2018','dd/mm/yyyy') as date_val,  'M' as gender,  'B' as cust_type from dual union all
select 25315 as custid ,  to_date('18/09/2018','dd/mm/yyyy') as date_val,  'F' as gender,  'C' as cust_type from dual union all
select 25316 as custid ,  to_date('18/09/2018','dd/mm/yyyy') as date_val,  'F' as gender,  'D' as cust_type from dual union all
select 25317 as custid ,  to_date('19/09/2018','dd/mm/yyyy') as date_val,  'M' as gender,  'D' as cust_type from dual union all
select 25318 as custid ,  to_date('19/09/2018','dd/mm/yyyy') as date_val,  'O' as gender,  'B' as cust_type from dual;
```

#### Query

```
SELECT year,
       quarter,
         NVL (a_m_total, 0)
       + NVL (a_f_total, 0)
       + NVL (a_o_total, 0)
       + NVL (b_m_total, 0)
       + NVL (b_f_total, 0)
       + NVL (b_o_total, 0)
       + NVL (c_m_total, 0)
       + NVL (c_f_total, 0)
       + NVL (c_o_total, 0)
       + NVL (d_m_total, 0)
       + NVL (d_f_total, 0)
       + NVL (d_o_total, 0)                                            AS quarter_total,
       NVL (a_m_total, 0) + NVL (a_f_total, 0) + NVL (a_o_total, 0)    AS a_total,
       NVL (a_m_total, 0)                                              AS a_m_total,
       NVL (a_f_total, 0)                                              AS a_f_total,
       NVL (a_o_total, 0)                                              AS a_o_total,
       NVL (b_m_total, 0) + NVL (b_f_total, 0) + NVL (b_o_total, 0)    AS b_total,
       NVL (b_m_total, 0)                                              AS b_m_total,
       NVL (b_f_total, 0)                                              AS b_f_total,
       NVL (b_o_total, 0)                                              AS b_o_total,
       NVL (c_m_total, 0) + NVL (c_f_total, 0) + NVL (c_o_total, 0)    AS c_total,
       NVL (c_m_total, 0)                                              AS c_m_total,
       NVL (c_f_total, 0)                                              AS c_f_total,
       NVL (c_o_total, 0)                                              AS c_o_total,
       NVL (d_m_total, 0) + NVL (d_f_total, 0) + NVL (d_o_total, 0)    AS d_total,
       NVL (d_m_total, 0)                                              AS d_m_total,
       NVL (d_f_total, 0)                                              AS d_f_total,
       NVL (d_o_total, 0)                                              AS d_o_total
  FROM (  SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM date_val)                     AS year,
                 CEIL (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM date_val) / 3)         AS quarter,
                 cust_type,
                 SUM (CASE gender WHEN 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)     AS total_m,
                 SUM (CASE gender WHEN 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)     AS total_f,
                 SUM (CASE gender WHEN 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)     AS total_o
            FROM cust_table
        GROUP BY EXTRACT (YEAR FROM date_val), CEIL (EXTRACT (MONTH FROM date_val) / 3), cust_type)
       PIVOT (MAX (total_m) AS m_total, MAX (total_f) AS f_total, MAX (total_o) AS o_total
             FOR cust_type
             IN ('A' AS a, 'B' AS b, 'C' AS c, 'D' AS d));
```

#### Result

```
   YEAR    QUARTER    QUARTER_TOTAL    A_TOTAL    A_M_TOTAL    A_F_TOTAL    A_O_TOTAL    B_TOTAL    B_M_TOTAL    B_F_TOTAL    B_O_TOTAL    C_TOTAL    C_M_TOTAL    C_F_TOTAL    C_O_TOTAL    D_TOTAL    D_M_TOTAL    D_F_TOTAL    D_O_TOTAL
_______ __________ ________________ __________ ____________ ____________ ____________ __________ ____________ ____________ ____________ __________ ____________ ____________ ____________ __________ ____________ ____________ ____________
   2018          3                7          1            0            0            1          2            1            0            1          1            0            1            0          3            1            2            0
   2018          4                3          2            1            0            0          1            0            1            0          1            0            0            1          0            0            0            0
```

Comment: I tried executing the query and count is too higher than existing count. The total count also is tooo higher...

Comment: This worked for tables having distinct values. Can you pls explain why pivot is used in group by and that max also

Comment: Can u pls explain @EJ Egyed

Comment: If the query is not working, please provide sample data to reproduce the issue where the query is not working and what the expected output should be from that data. No it is not finding distinct records from the source table.  The `MAX` function is needed because an aggregate function is needed to pivot data. You can change that to `MIN` or `SUM` or any other aggregate function if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

I used "list" as a source table, then COUNTed distinctly "custid"s for gender category by using PIVOT clause. and assumed that the quarter is "YYYY-Q" formatted. as a last query I summed the counts for each gender for each cust_type to get the result you needed using the pivot table named "cg".

```
with 
 list (custid, "date", gender, cust_type) as (
  select 25309, to_date('29/10/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'M', 'A' from dual union all
  select 25310, to_date('09/11/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'F', 'B' from dual union all
  select 25311, to_date('10/11/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'O', 'C' from dual union all
  select 25312, to_date('18/09/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'F', 'D' from dual union all
  select 25313, to_date('18/09/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'O', 'A' from dual union all
  select 25314, to_date('18/09/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'M', 'B' from dual union all
  select 25315, to_date('18/09/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'F', 'C' from dual union all
  select 25316, to_date('18/09/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'F', 'D' from dual union all
  select 25317, to_date('19/09/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'M', 'D' from dual union all
  select 25318, to_date('19/09/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'O', 'B' from dual 
)
,cg as (
  select * from (select custid, to_char("date", 'YYYY-Q') as quarter, cust_type, gender from list)
    pivot (count(distinct custid) as gender for gender in('F' F, 'M' M, 'O' O))
)
select 
  quarter, 
  ----------
  sum(case when cust_type = 'A' then nvl(f_gender,0)+nvl(m_gender,0)+nvl(o_gender,0) else 0 end) as a_total,
  sum(case when cust_type = 'A' then f_gender else 0 end) as a_f,
  sum(case when cust_type = 'A' then m_gender else 0 end) as a_m,
  sum(case when cust_type = 'A' then o_gender else 0 end) as a_o,
  ----------
  sum(case when cust_type = 'B' then nvl(f_gender,0)+nvl(m_gender,0)+nvl(o_gender,0) else 0 end) as b_total,
  sum(case when cust_type = 'B' then f_gender else 0 end) as b_f,
  sum(case when cust_type = 'B' then m_gender else 0 end) as b_m,
  sum(case when cust_type = 'B' then o_gender else 0 end) as b_o,
  ----------
  sum(case when cust_type = 'C' then nvl(f_gender,0)+nvl(m_gender,0)+nvl(o_gender,0) else 0 end) as c_total,
  sum(case when cust_type = 'C' then f_gender else 0 end) as c_f,
  sum(case when cust_type = 'C' then m_gender else 0 end) as c_m,
  sum(case when cust_type = 'C' then o_gender else 0 end) as c_o,
  ----------
  sum(case when cust_type = 'D' then nvl(f_gender,0)+nvl(m_gender,0)+nvl(o_gender,0) else 0 end) as d_total,
  sum(case when cust_type = 'D' then f_gender else 0 end) as d_f,
  sum(case when cust_type = 'D' then m_gender else 0 end) as d_m,
  sum(case when cust_type = 'D' then o_gender else 0 end) as d_o
from cg
group by quarter;
```

If your source table name is TOT_POP_DET and have columns "custid", "date", "gender", "cust_type" then you can ignore my data preparation "list" query and start with "cg". I used CTE (common table expression) but using subquery is fine as well. "list" and "cg" are CTEs.
I mean you can start

```
with cg as (
  select * from (select custid, to_char("date", 'YYYY-Q') as quarter, cust_type, gender from TOT_POP_DET)
  pivot (count(distinct custid) as gender for gender in('F' F, 'M' M, 'O' O))
  )
  ,...
```

As you will notice "cg" is distinct count by quarter and cust_type.
PIVOT syntax is as below:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT column1, column2, .. FROM table(s) WHERE condition(s))
PIVOT (aggregate_function(column2) FOR column2 IN ( expr1, expr2, ... expr_n))
ORDER BY expression [ ASC | DESC ];
```

firstly, selected the needed columns from the source table, then count(distinct custid) as aggregation_function, gender FOR category column, IN (gender list). so got the first result set by quarter and cust_type.

```
QUARTER CUST_TYPE   F_GENDER    M_GENDER    O_GENDER
2018-3      A           0           0           1
2018-3      B           0           1           1
2018-3      C           1           0           0
2018-3      D           2           1           0
2018-4      A           0           1           0
2018-4      B           1           0           0
2018-4      C           0           0           1
```

then used this result set, grouped and summed counts with each case to transpose the data to get the final result set.

```
QUARTER A_TOTAL A_F A_M A_O B_TOTAL B_F B_M B_O C_TOTAL C_F C_M C_O D_TOTAL D_F D_M D_O
2018-4      1   0   1   0       1   1   0   0       1   0   0   1       0   0   0   0
2018-3      1   0   0   1       2   0   1   1       1   1   0   0       3   2   1   0
```

Additionally, if you change "YYYY-Q" to "YYYY" in PIVOT and execute the query you can get the result by year as below

```
QUARTER A_TOTAL A_F A_M A_O B_TOTAL B_F B_M B_O C_TOTAL C_F C_M C_O D_TOTAL D_F D_M D_O
2018    2       0   1   1       3   1   1   1       2   1   0   1       3   2   1   0
```

tried an explanation hope it helps

Comment: Could you please add some explanation about how your sql statement answers the question, to make it more useful for others who may be experiencing the same problem?

Comment: Hi can u pls explain this.. as I have a table,how can I implement without ur list?can u pls explain

Comment: Hi akr, after @RobertDean 's comment I'd added a bit explanation but I guess it was very summary. now tried to explain with more detail. hope it's ok.

Comment: Hi @NurayBiliz i tested ur query with my data, the count seems to be too higher than actual count. Not sure where its going wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

I hope that the answer could help you. Find it in this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4229be6bdd448eff312b3d918f84f232)
The version of SQL is Oracle 11g. The `cte` manipulates your data to produce and produces two columns for your year and quarter. After that, you need to perform a `COUNT` based on the parameters that you want.

```
with cte AS(SELECT custid, gender, cust_type, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cust_date) AS cust_year,
CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM cust_date)<4 THEN 1
  WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM cust_date)<7 THEN 2
  WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM cust_date)<10 THEN 3
  ELSE 4
  END AS quarter
FROM your_Table)
SELECT gender, cust_type, cust_year, quarter, COUNT(custid)
FROM cte
GROUP BY gender, cust_type, cust_year, quarter
ORDER BY cust_year, quarter, cust_type
```